# Most efficient way to parse xml data from PHP SOAP response w/ SimpleXML?

Tags: php, xml, soap

I have an XML dataset that I am consuming via SOAP through PHP. I am trying to parse out the values from the xml such that I can use those values to populate into a database. I've been searching around for a while to find out the best way to do this. Here is an example of some xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<soap:Envelope xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
  <soap:Body>
<PaymentNotification xmlns="http://apilistener.envoyservices.com">
  <payment>
    <uniqueReference>ESDEUR11039872</uniqueReference>      
    <epacsReference>74348dc0-cbf0-df11-b725-001ec9e61285</epacsReference>
    <postingDate>2010-11-15T15:19:45</postingDate>
    <bankCurrency>EUR</bankCurrency>
    <bankAmount>1.00</bankAmount>
    <appliedCurrency>EUR</appliedCurrency>
    <appliedAmount>1.00</appliedAmount>
    <countryCode>ES</countryCode>
    <bankInformation>Sean Wood</bankInformation>
  <merchantReference>ESDEUR11039872</merchantReference>
   </payment>
    </PaymentNotification>
  </soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>
```

Using SimpleXMl and namespaces/xpath, I have access to the  tag and the values within. However the only way I seem to be able to parse out the values is to loop through each element in the  node, check the name of it, and if it matches my string comparison then assign that to an array variable. I have to parse out multiple payments. For example:

```
//all payments
foreach($data->children() as $child) {
   //one payment
   foreach($child->children() as $subChild) {

     switch($subChild->getName()) {
        case "bankCurrency":
           $newPayment['bankCurrency'] = (string)$subChild;
       break;
    case "bankPayment":
       $newPayment['bankAmount'] = (string)$subChild;
       break;
    }
  }
}
```

Is this the best way to do it? Or have I completely missed some other way somewhere? Thanks!

Comment: Why not use [`SoapClient`](http://php.net/manual/en/class.soapclient.php)?

Comment: I think You should use PHP build SOAP implementation for this purpose, then You don't have to play with plain XMLs at all.

Comment: oh I've used the PHP soap client to obtain the XML already. This is the result of that. I took the response, ran it through the simple_xml_load_string, and now have the SimpleXML objects that I am trying to sort through. Is that not the best approach?

Answer (score 0):

After much trial and error, I realized that I could actually access the xml elements in a far easier fashion. From within the initial loop, I can access the elements directly by using $child->bankCurrency. No need to go into the inner loop and do any of that parsing. I'm finally wrapping my head around this PHP xml stuff.